# How to change the size of the axis, ticks and labels for a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, size

I'd like to Change the size of the axis, because the size of label in small

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(csv_reader["loss"],label='perte de formation')
plt.plot(csv_reader["val_loss"],label='perte de validation')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Log-loss')

plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the font size globally:

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
```

Or you can change it for individual components:

```
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=12)

plt.rc('axes', labelsize=12)

plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)

plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)
```